# osgi.wiring.package=com.bedas.ima missing requirement error in karaf

Tags: maven, apache-karaf, osgi-bundle, fuseesb, jbossfuse

I want to make an application with using `Apache Camel`.I wrote the `route` in `xml` file.But `Karaf container` does not recognize the package that i wrote for `beans`.Here is my `xml` and `pom.xml` files:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more contributor 
    license agreements. See the NOTICE file distributed with this work for additional 
    information regarding copyright ownership. The ASF licenses this file to 
    You under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License"); you may not use 
    this file except in compliance with the License. You may obtain a copy of 
    the License at http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0 Unless required 
    by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software distributed under the 
    License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS 
    OF ANY KIND, either express or implied. See the License for the specific 
    language governing permissions and limitations under the License. -->

<!-- START SNIPPET: e1 -->
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:camel="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring"
    xmlns:cxf="http://camel.apache.org/schema/cxf" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
       http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring/camel-spring.xsd
       http://camel.apache.org/schema/cxf http://camel.apache.org/schema/cxf/camel-cxf.xsd">


    <bean id="aysProcessor" class="com.bedas.ima.AysProcessor" />

    <bean id="executor" class="java.util.concurrent.Executors"
        factory-method="newFixedThreadPool">
        <constructor-arg index="0" value="16" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="activemq" class="org.apache.activemq.camel.component.ActiveMQComponent">
        <property name="brokerURL" value="tcp://localhost:61616" />
        <property name="userName" value="akin" />
        <property name="password" value="akin123" />

    </bean>


<!--    <import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf.xml" /> -->


    <!-- this is the CXF web service we use as the front end -->
    <cxf:cxfEndpoint id="ima-okuma"
        address="http://localhost:8168/sep/services/cxf/imaOkumaCxfService"
        serviceName="s:ImaOkumaServiceImplService" wsdlURL="META-INF/wsdl/imaokuma.wsdl"
        xmlns:s="http://service.cxf.ws.sep.bedas.com/" />

    <cxf:cxfEndpoint id="ays-service"
        address="http://localhost:8080/ays/services/begisService"
        serviceName="s:BegisServiceImplService" wsdlURL="META-INF/wsdl/aysBegis.wsdl"
        serviceClass="com.bedas.ays.ws.service.BegisService"
        xmlns:s="http://service.ws.ays.bedas.com/" />

<!--        <bean id="myNameStrategy" class="org.apache.camel.dataformat.soap.name.ServiceInterfaceStrategy"> -->
<!--     <constructor-arg value="com.bedas.sep.ws.cxf.service.ImaOkumaCxfService"/> -->
<!-- <constructor-arg value="true"/> -->
<!-- </bean> -->

<!-- <bean id="enrichBean" class="com.bedas.ays.ws.service.EnrichBean"/> -->


    <!-- this is the Camel route which proxies the real web service and forwards 
        SOAP requests to it -->
    <!-- <route errorHandlerRef="dlc" id="imaRoute2"> --><!-- <from uri="activemq:queue:imaokumaq?disableTimeToLive=true"/> --><!-- <to uri="http://10.212.80.138:8080/sep/services/cxf/imaOkumaCxfService"/> --><!-- </route> -->
    <camelContext trace="false" errorHandlerRef="defaultEH" id="ImaOkuma" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">

    <errorHandler type="DefaultErrorHandler" id="defaultEH">
        <redeliveryPolicy maximumRedeliveries="0" retryAttemptedLogLevel="WARN"/>
    </errorHandler>
    <errorHandler type="DeadLetterChannel" deadLetterUri="activemq:queue:imaOkumaERROR" useOriginalMessage="true" id="dlc">
        <redeliveryPolicy maximumRedeliveries="0"/>
    </errorHandler>
    <dataFormats>
    <jaxb id="myJaxb" prettyPrint="true" contextPath="com.bedas.sep.ws.cxf.service"/>
  </dataFormats>
    <route errorHandlerRef="dlc" id="imaRoute1">
        <from uri="cxf:bean:ima-okuma?dataFormat=MESSAGE"/>
        <wireTap uri="activemq:queue:aysq?jmsMessageType=Object"/>
        <inOnly uri="activemq:queue:imaokumaq"/>
        <to uri="velocity:response.vm"/>
<!--         <camel:transform><camel:constant>OK</camel:constant></camel:transform> -->
<!--         <to uri="cxf:bean:ays-service?dataFormat=POJO"/> -->

<!--         <convertBodyTo type="com.bedas.ays.ws.service.BegisModel"/>  -->
<!--        <marshal> -->
<!--         <soapjaxb contextPath="com.bedas.sep.ws.cxf.service" version="1.1" elementNameStrategyRef="myNameStrategy"/> -->
<!--     </marshal> -->
<!--         <multicast parallelProcessing="true" executorServiceRef="executor" stopOnException="false"> -->
<!--            <inOnly uri="activemq:queue:imaokumaq"/> -->
<!--            <to uri="aysProcessor"/> -->
<!--         </multicast> -->
    </route>
    <route errorHandlerRef="dlc" id="imaRoute2">
    <from uri="activemq:queue:aysq?jmsMessageType=Object"/>
    <camel:log message="BURADAYIMMMM"></camel:log>
    <to uri="aysProcessor"/>
<!--         <unmarshal> -->
<!--         <soapjaxb contextPath="com.bedas.sep.ws.cxf.service" version="1.1" elementNameStrategyRef="myNameStrategy"/> -->
<!--     </unmarshal> -->

<!--         <convertBodyTo type="com.bedas.ays.ws.service.BegisModel"/>  -->
<!--         <from uri="aysProcessor"/> -->
<!--         <to uri="cxf:bean:ays-service?dataFormat=POJO"/> -->
    </route>
</camelContext>

</beans>
<!-- END SNIPPET: e1 -->
```

When i make `mvn:install` and deploy it in `fuse karaf container`,it throws the exception in the question title.Here is my `pom.xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more contributor 
    license agreements. See the NOTICE file distributed with this work for additional 
    information regarding copyright ownership. The ASF licenses this file to 
    You under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License"); you may not use 
    this file except in compliance with the License. You may obtain a copy of 
    the License at http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0 Unless required 
    by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software distributed under the 
    License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS 
    OF ANY KIND, either express or implied. See the License for the specific 
    language governing permissions and limitations under the License. -->
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>examples</artifactId>
        <version>2.12.3</version>
        <relativePath></relativePath>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>ima-okuma</artifactId>
    <name>Camel :: Example :: CXF :: Proxy</name>
    <description>An example which uses Camel to proxy a web service</description>
    <packaging>bundle</packaging>

    <properties>
        <camel.osgi.export.pkg>
            com.bedas.sep.ws.cxf.service*
            com.bedas.ays.ws.service*
            com.bedas.ima*
        </camel.osgi.export.pkg>
        <camel.osgi.private.pkg>
            com.bedas.sep.ws.cxf.service.imaokuma
            com.bedas.ays.ws.service.begismodel
            com.bedas.ima.AysProcessor
        </camel.osgi.private.pkg>
        <!-- to avoid us import bunch of cxf package -->
        <camel.osgi.dynamic>*</camel.osgi.dynamic>
    </properties>


    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-core</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
<!--        <dependency> -->
<!--   <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId> -->
<!--   <artifactId>camel-soap</artifactId> -->
<!--   </dependency> -->

        <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
    <artifactId>camel-spring</artifactId>

</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
  <artifactId>camel-jaxb</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
  <artifactId>camel-soap</artifactId>
</dependency>

        <dependency>

    <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
    <artifactId>camel-velocity</artifactId>
    <scope>provided</scope>

</dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-http</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-cxf</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- cxf -->
        <!-- used by the real web service -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws</artifactId>
            <version>${cxf-version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- regular http transport -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-transports-http</artifactId>
            <version>${cxf-version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- logging -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- cxf web container for unit testing -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-transports-http-jetty</artifactId>
            <version>${cxf-version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
            <artifactId>activemq-pool</artifactId>

        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
            <artifactId>activemq-camel</artifactId>

            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
                    <artifactId>camel-jms</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-jms</artifactId>

        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
            <artifactId>activemq-kahadb-store</artifactId>

        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>

        <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <includePluginDependencies>false</includePluginDependencies>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <!-- CXF wsdl2java generator, will plugin to the compile goal -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
                <artifactId>cxf-codegen-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>generate-sources</id>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <sourceRoot>${basedir}/src/main/java</sourceRoot>
                            <wsdlOptions>
                                <wsdlOption>
                                    <wsdl>${basedir}/src/main/resources/META-INF/wsdl/imaokuma.wsdl</wsdl>
                                </wsdlOption>
                            </wsdlOptions>
                        </configuration>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>wsdl2java</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>generate-sources1</id>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <sourceRoot>${basedir}/src/main/java</sourceRoot>
                            <wsdlOptions>
                                <wsdlOption>
                                    <wsdl>${basedir}/src/main/resources/META-INF/wsdl/aysBegis.wsdl</wsdl>
                                </wsdlOption>
                            </wsdlOptions>
                        </configuration>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>wsdl2java</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>


            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
                <artifactId>camel-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${project.version}</version>
            </plugin>

<!--             <plugin> -->
<!--                 <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId> -->
<!--                 <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId> -->
<!--                 <extensions>true</extensions> -->
<!--                 <configuration> -->
<!--                     <instructions> -->
<!--                         <Import-Package>*</Import-Package> -->
<!--                         <EXPORT-PACKAGE>${camel.osgi.export.pkg}</EXPORT-PACKAGE> -->
<!--                         <_failok>true</_failok> -->
<!--                     </instructions> -->
<!--                 </configuration> -->
<!--             </plugin> -->


        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: Hi, can you post the MANIFEST.MF of this bundle?

Comment: How you solved.